# Dumping response headers in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-headers, response

I know how to get the *request* headers in MVC, but how do I get *all* of the *response* headers once a request is complete and display them, for example, on a page for debugging purposes? I realize I can just use chrome's network tab for this, but I am curious.

For example, chrome's network tab will show 8-9 response headers, but if I call `Response.Headers.AllKeys` I only get 2 keys in the collection where I would think I would get 8. Why is this?

Comment: That's what Fiddler does, and the F12 tools of all browsers. Debugging proxies like Fiddler offer more features that browsers

Comment: IIS adds its own headers outside of the controller execution, so the question is do you want all headers or just the headers .NET manipulates?

Comment: I would like to get all response headers, basically all that you see in the response headers section of the chrome debugger's network tab

Comment: If you want to display them on the page, you'd have to use some Javascript because you have no way to know what has intercepted and added/changed headers since your app set them up.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is probably the most popular tool for this. It's a debugging proxy that can capture requests and responses, pretty-print Json, XML contents and even allows you to create and post new requests

If you want to display the headers on a page, you could add [Glimpse](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse) to the application. Unfortunately the project was abandoned. It works well for ASP.NET MVC5 projects but no new features were added and there's no .NET Core support.

That said, the available features are very helpful - request and response headers, timings, SQL queries, a timeline view of the entire request including database queries, exceptions etc.

Comment: OP knows how to view them in Chrome dev tools so I'm not sure this really helps all that much.

Comment: @DavidG Fiddler is more advanced than any browser's tools

Comment: How will it do that?